# Error al enviar variable String a una funcion

Tags: javascript

Buen día! Estoy teniendo un problema con el pasaje de variables entre funciones. Mi idea es enviar desde el "Botón borrar" una variable a la función deleteProduct(string) y generar un alert con el dato que llegue para probar. El problema está en que me da el siguiente error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: letras is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM22 tables.html:460:23)`

Agradezco toda la ayuda posible. Probe haciendo escapes de string, utilizando la concatenacion ${variable} y desestructurando el JSON proveniente desde el backend. Un dato curioso es que las variables INTEGER se envían sin ningún problema. El error surge con strings nada mas.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Los códigos son los siguientes:

```
  const productListPeticion = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/productos', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  });

  const productList = await productListPeticion.json();
  let listProduct = ''; // ARRAYLIST DE TODOS LOS OBJETOS DE LA DB
  for (let product of productList){
    // ACCIONES   
    let string = "letras" 
    let botonAgregar ='<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"> <i class="fas fa-check"></i> </a> '
    let botonBorrar = '<a onclick="deleteProduct('+ string +') " href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle"> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a> '
    let botonEditar = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></a> '
    //Modelo Producto
    let newProduct ='<tr> <td>' + product._id + '</td><td>'+ product.nombre + '</td><td>' + product.cantidad + '</td><td>' + product.precio + '</td> <td>'+ botonEditar + botonBorrar +'</td></tr>'
    listProduct += newProduct
  } 
  document.querySelector('#dataTable tbody').outerHTML = listProduct;
};

// Opciones de Producto.

function deleteProduct(string){
alert(string)
}
```